# Analytic function to compute statuses of different rows

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I am using Oracle 10g and I want to compute different status of rows containing in table `tmp_ord`.It contains below data.
[image: Sample_Data]

There are below set of rules for marking the status

1. There should be at least one order_position whose status is 'ABC' and there should be no order_position whose status is 'NON-ABC' with same corresponding order_id then mark status as 'ABC'.
2. There should be at least one order_position whose status is 'NON-ABC' and there should be no order_position whose corresponding status is 'ABC' then mark status as 'NON-ABC'.
3. If there are at least one order_position whose status is 'ABC' and at least one order_position whose status is 'NON-ABC' for same ORDER_ID then mark status as 'AMB'.
4. If there is only order_position whose status is NULL for corresponding ORDER_ID then mark status as 'UNKNOWN'.
5. Suppose ABC and NULL is present then it should return ABC, If NOn-ABC and NULL is present then it should return 'NON-ABC'.........But if only single NULL value is present then it should return 'UNKNOWN' however if there are ALL' NULL' values associated with ORDER_ID UNIFORMLY then it should return 'NULL'

I have written below query to compute the data but getting one NULL value corresponding to ORDER_ID=6.

```
SELECT  distinct ORDER_ID,CASE WHEN R1=0 THEN 'UNKNOWN'
                              WHEN R1=1 AND ORDER_STATUS='ABC'  THEN 'ABC'
                              WHEN R1=1 AND ORDER_STATUS<>'ABC' THEN 'NON-ABC'
                              WHEN R1>1                         THEN 'MD'
                              END STATUS
                     ,CASE WHEN R2=0 THEN 'UNKNOWN'
                          WHEN R2=1 AND ORDER_STATUS_1='ABC'  THEN 'ABC'
                          WHEN R2=1 AND ORDER_STATUS_1<>'ABC' THEN 'NON-ABC'
                          WHEN R2>1                         THEN 'MD'
                          END STATUS_1
FROM
(
SELECT  ORDER_ID,ORDER_STATUS,ORDER_STATUS_1,
 COUNT(DISTINCT order_status) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID) R1 
,COUNT(DISTINCT order_status_1) OVER (PARTITION BY ORDER_ID) R2
FROM TMP_ORD
ORDER BY ORDER_ID
);
```

I am getting below output. Please let me know how I can suppress row associated with ORDER_ID=6 which is giving STATUS=NULL... It should 'ABC' as it contains at least one 'ABC' and no status with 'NON-ABC'.
[image]

Comment: I have written below query to compute the data but getting one NULL value corrosponding to ORDER_ID=6.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a stab at it, but not knowing the context, and especially what "ABC" and "NON-ABC" really represent it's a bit hard to get it right.

You said that 6 should return "ABC" - Would it be acceptable in your specific case to consider "NULL" as equivalent to non-"NON-ABC"? 
And therefore "NULL"="ABC"? If this is ok for you, try using NVL(STATUS, "ABC") and things should work.

But this is taking some pretty large assumption about the meaning of your data. Is it possible for an order to have all of its rows with STATUS=NULL? 
If yes, what should your function return? ABC?

---

Alternatively, you can try being stricter with your definition of "NON-ABC" try replacing:

```
 WHEN ... ORDER_STATUS<>'ABC' THEN 'NON-ABC'
```

with

```
 WHEN ... (ORDER_STATUS<>'ABC'AND ORDER_STATUS IS NOT NULL) THEN 'NON-ABC'
```

and see what you get

Comment: Because of confidentiality, I unable to put exact data hence I created an example. Suppose ABC and NULL is present then it should return ABC, If NOn-ABC and NULL is present then it should return 'NON-ABC'.........But if only single NULL value is present then it should return 'UNKNOWN' however if there are ALL' NULL' values associated with ORDER_ID UNIFORMLY then it should return 'NULL'

Comment: I have tried using NVL but it is getting fail for condition NO.4 as it is marking it as some value and I am not getting R or R1=0 for ORDER_ID whose contain only single row and that too NULL

Comment: Please check above comments

Comment: So you were missing a couple rules in your original question, i.e. how to manage NULLs. Please update the question - then we maybe try using EXISTS to properly manage this

Answer (score 0):

Point 5 is a bit unclear (for me), but this query should do the work:

```
with o0 as (
  select order_id,
    sum(decode (order_status, 'ABC', 1, 0)) s0_abc,
    sum(decode (order_status, 'ABC', 0, null, 0, 1)) s0_xyz,
    sum(decode (order_status, NULL, 1, 0)) s0_null,
    sum(case when order_status is null and order_position is null 
      then 1 else 0 end) s0_null_op
  from tmp_ord group by order_id),
o1 as (
  select order_id,
    sum(decode (order_status_1, 'ABC', 1, 0)) s1_abc,
    sum(decode (order_status_1, 'ABC', 0, null, 0, 1)) s1_xyz,
    sum(decode (order_status_1, NULL, 1, 0)) s1_null,
    sum(case when order_status_1 is null and order_position is null 
      then 1 else 0 end) s1_null_op
  from tmp_ord group by order_id)
select order_id,
    case 
      when s0_abc > 0 and s0_xyz = 0 then 'ABC'
      when s0_abc = 0 and s0_xyz > 0 then 'NON-ABC'
      when s0_abc > 0 and s0_xyz > 0 then 'AMB'
      when s0_null_op = s0_null then null
      else 'UNKNOWN'
    end status,
    case 
      when s1_abc > 0 and s1_xyz = 0 then 'ABC'
      when s1_abc = 0 and s1_xyz > 0 then 'NON-ABC'
      when s1_abc > 0 and s1_xyz > 0 then 'AMB'
      when s1_null_op = s1_null then null
      else 'UNKNOWN'
    end status_1
  from o0 join o1 using (order_id)
  order by order_id
```

Results:

```
  ORDER_ID STATUS  STATUS_1
---------- ------- --------
         1 AMB     ABC
         2 AMB     AMB
         3 AMB     AMB
         4 NON-ABC NON-ABC
         5 ABC     ABC
         6 ABC     ABC
         7 UNKNOWN UNKNOWN

7 rows selected
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for misguiding you guys.
If you read my all rules clearly, it has mentioned to take count of **'ORDER_POSITION'** with respect to 'ORDER_STATUS' and 'ORDER_ID'.
In my query **(Which I posted in a Question)** I had taken a count of ORDER_STATUS with respect to 'ORDER_ID'.
Please Find below Solution for it.

```
SELECT ORDER_ID
,CASE 
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT  = 0    AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT=0  AND TOTAL_COUNT=1 THEN 'UNKNOWN'
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT >= 1    AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT=0                    THEN 'ABC'
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT  = 0    AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT>=1                   THEN 'NON_ABC'
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT >= 1    AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT>=1                   THEN 'AMB'
END STATUS
,CASE 
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT_1  = 0  AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT_1=0 AND TOTAL_COUNT=1 THEN 'UNKNOWN'
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT_1 >= 1  AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT_1=0                   THEN 'ABC'
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT_1  = 0  AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT_1>=1                  THEN 'NON_ABC'
WHEN ABC_STATUS_CNT_1 >= 1  AND NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT_1>=1                  THEN 'AMB'
END STATUS_1
FROM
(
SELECT ORDER_ID,COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_STATUS   =  'ABC' THEN ORDER_POSITION ELSE NULL END) ABC_STATUS_CNT
,COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_STATUS   <> 'ABC' THEN ORDER_POSITION ELSE NULL END) NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT
,COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_STATUS_1 =  'ABC' THEN ORDER_POSITION ELSE NULL END) ABC_STATUS_CNT_1
,COUNT(CASE WHEN ORDER_STATUS_1 <> 'ABC' THEN ORDER_POSITION ELSE NULL END) NON_ABC_STATUS_CNT_1
,COUNT(ORDER_POSITION) AS TOTAL_COUNT
FROM TMP_ORD_BNG2A
GROUP BY ORDER_ID
);
```

[image]

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct to close this topic :-)